# How to make master page not to be cache?

Tags: asp.net

I have login and logout buttons in master page.So when user logged in againg if clicked back button from browser the cached data againg shwing.Even i cant make whole page not to be because my application is e commerce.Kindly any one give solution....

Answer (score 0):

add these on page_load() of whatever the page u inherit from masterpage

```
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

Comment: i need to to cache the content pages except master page.If place this code in child pages whole page will not be a cache..

Comment: In that case try adding this to master page

Comment: but master page contains content page also..if I put in master page obivously whole page will not be cache.

Comment: did you try that? Did it stop contents from caching?

Comment: Your requirement is unique. Usually developers want to prevent cach site-wide. If you can explain what you are trying to achive, may be someone can give a work around

Comment: This code wroks me like a charm....Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
            Response.Expires = 0;
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);
            //Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
            //Response.Headers.Add("Pragma:", "no-cache");
            Response.CacheControl = "No-Cache";
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Comment: Pls put this as an answer and make your own post as answered. So others may know the fix too. Thanks

Comment: This below code worked me like a charm..put below code in code behind page load method of master page and inherits page..login and logout status will not change when user click back button.         


            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
            Response.Expires = 0;
            Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);
            Response.CacheControl = "No-Cache";
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);